# What are the must-have filters for a new photographer?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters

What filters are good and why?

Comment: I don't really think that camera body is a decisive factor when it comes to filter selection. You might want to look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-are-your-preferred-filters-for-certain-subjects

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### To Summarise

This is an attempt to summarise the widely-held opinions of photographers in general.
I believe this is a fair distillation of views.

- Adding any filter risks adding **lens flare** and reducing sharpness
- The effect of most filters can be **reproduced in post** processing
- The only filter which cannot be adequately reproduced in post is a **polarising filter** (particularly when used to remove / reduce reflections / glare).
- **Neutral Density** filters are sometimes necessary.  For example: when the photographer wants to reduce the amount of light entering the lens to allow a wide apperture and a long exposure (for example, when photographing flowing water).
- **UV Filters**:

  - Many photographers feel that it is worthwhile to put a UV filter on the front of every lens, on the basis that this will protect the front lens element - from dust, scratches and catastrophic damage if the lens is dropped.  In other words, it is a kind of insurance policy against lens damage.  I understand that Scott Kelby takes this position.
  - Many (other) photographers believe that this practice is not worthwhile:  they may feel that the reduction in image quality (actual or potential) is not justified by this "insurance policy".  I have heard Scott Bourne articulate this belief.

I hope this is a fair and sensitive summary ;)

Comment: It should be noted that on most new Canon lenses, the "weather sealing" feature is only fully realized when a filter is screwed on. This is usually noted in the Canon details about the lens. I recently purchased the EF 16-35mm f/2.8 L USM II, and it is only fully weather sealed when a filter is applied...at the least a UVP, but a polarizer or any other filter will also suffice.

Comment: @jrista, I didn't know that - it's a top tip!  ;)

Comment: @jrista - It is  the first time I read about this as well. However, I speculate that the addition of the filter does not really **seal** anything that wasn't sealed before. It is merely protecting the front lens element from the elements, this completing the weather protection suite.

Comment: @Ysap: At least on Canon L-series lenses, there is a tiny hole in the mount for the front lens element. It allows airflow as elements move around during focusing or zoom. "Full" weather sealing is not possible unless this tiny hole is protected, which is where the filter comes in. So its more than just protecting the front element, adding a filter does actually play a role in full weather sealing.

Comment: @jrista - that's very interesting piece of information. I will certainly look at my 70-200/2.8LIS when back home. This makes me wonder, though: if there is a hole there, for a purpose, then won't the sealing filter actually interfere with the normal operation of the lens?!

Comment: @Ysap: Airflow just needs to be between moving element groups. You don't actually need "fresh" air, you just need to allow air to move around. Think of it this way...if you zoom, and that requires that the front lens element move toward the back of the lens, and the back lens element move toward the front of the lens, then the air between those two needs to flow past those moving lens elements. Its a fixed volume of air, but how that fixed volume is distributed inside the lens changes as you focus and zoom. You can still have a sealed lens, so long as you allow air movement within the seal.

Comment: @jrista - that was exactly what I was thinking when making my first comment, which makes the whole "hole" thing even more mysterious. If you can effectively seal that hole with a filter, then why is it there in the first place? Unless the front element itself moves relative to the filter ring. In this case, the filter just closes a non-changing volume, and the air flows in and out of the inner partial volume. But I don't think this is the case with the L lenses.

Comment: @ysap: I guess I would have to create a diagram demonstrating what I am trying to describe. Think about it this way. Assume you have a three element lens, with a movable front element, a fixed middle element, and a movable back element. The volume between the front and middle element is *dynamic*, as is the volume between the middle and back element. Lets assume (however contrived) that to reduce the focal length, the front and back elements need to move towards the middle element. That means the volume between the front and middle elements SHRINKS! The same goes for the middle and back...

Comment: To accommodate the shifting volumes, one of two things can happen. You either compress the air in the volume between the first/middle and back/middle elements increasing pressure, OR...you create a pathway that allows air to move past the front and back elements, maintaining pressure (reducing the amount of air as volume decreases.) Conversely, if you expand the volume between the front/middle and back/middle elements, you either lower pressure, or allow air to move past the front and back elements to fill the additional volume.

Comment: Without a filter, particulate, water, etc. can enter through the hole in the mount for the front lens element in a sealed lens when you increase the volume inside the lens. Adding a filter doesn't prevent airflow, however it does keep the air that is currently inside the lens the same air...it prevents other air, possibly filled with particulate, from entering.

Comment: @jrista - this is exactly what I meant in the "Unless the front element itself moves relative to the filter ring" part. Again, as far as I remember, it does not move, but I can be wrong (and it can also be a private case for the 70-200/2.8.

Comment: @ysap: Not all front lens elements move. Most zoom lenses have moving element groups, and all internal focusing lenses have moving element groups. The simple point is that there needs to be some way for pressure to equalize as those elements move around. In the case of my 16-35mm L II, its front element does move, and the holes for airflow is clearly visible. You can see images of this lens here: http://the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-16-35mm-f-2.8-L-II-USM-Lens-Review.aspx, the holes are visible in the metal mount right next to the lens element.

Comment: @jrista - OK, I went to check my 70-200/2.8LIS - as I remembered there is no movement apparent of the front element while zooming or focusing. Accordingly, I could not see any visible hole there. The fixed size can be seen in the third image in http://the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-70-200mm-f-2.8-L-USM-Lens-Review.aspx.

Comment: This is an awesome discussion - could you guys turn it into a question / answer?  That way, it would really benefit the community.

Comment: @ysap: Correct, the 70-200 is all internal focusing/zoom, so the front element does not move. Airflow is still possible internally, as there is space between movable elements and the lens casing. I noted that most, but not all, Canon lenses require a filter to complete weather sealing. Most of the newest black L-series Canon zooms have a moving front element that slides inside of a tube. The filter screws into the tube rather than the front element mount, so it does not appear that the lens changes length when zooming, however it is. The white lenses are a bit different.

Comment: @jrista - so in that case, putting a filter does not block the airflow around the front element, and there is no problem. The only time where a problem can arise is when you have a moving front element and a filter attached to it (and moves with it as well). Then you confine a fixed volume in front of the element and this may interfere with the movement of the element.

Comment: @jrista - If I'm inspired later today, I'll try to make this a question/answer, as @AJ Finch suggested.

Comment: @ysap: Your front element is fixed, so no airflow around it is necessary. If you look at the back end of your lens, and focus or zoom, you should be able to see some elements moving inside of the lens. You should also notice that even when the back lens element group is as far back as it can go, it is not "sealed", so you do have airflow there. When used on a sealed body, the air volume within the lens and camera is fixed, but the individual volumes between moving element groups can still change. Airflow around the front element is only necessary if it moves, and a hole only when sealed.

Answer (score 10):

Filters that are useful for digital photography:

- Polarizing filter. This will cut through haze and reduce glare. Useful for landscapes as this will darken the sky by cutting out polarized light and also reduce haze making objects in the distance look clearer. Technically you need a *circular* polazrizing filter if you want automatic focus and metering (most filters are this type).
- ND filter. Simply cuts out light, useful for increasing the shutter speed for artistic effects or flash sync or allowing wide apertures in bright daylight. Also available as a graduated filter (i.e. one that starts out clear and gets progressively darker, useful for taming scenes with high dynamic range, such as bright skies).
- Infrared filter. Technically a visible light blocking filter. Allows infra-red photography using a standard DSLR. Requires very long exposures due to the camera's built in IR filter cutting out most of the incoming light, but can have spectacular results.

Whether you should buy any of these depends entirely on what sort of photography you plan on doing and what your budget is!

Other popular filters for film use such as coloured filters have limited use in digital photography, see this question for more details: [Are there reasons to use colour filters with digital cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/586/are-colour-filters-worth-using-with-digital-cameras)

Comment: Merged from: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/which-filters-should-i-be-buying-for-canon-eos-550-d-18-55mm-and-55-250mm-lenses

Answer (score 6):

One important thing to have in addition to filters is an assortment of stepping rings.  This way you can primarily invest in filters of a single size, say 77mm and have inexpensive stepping rings to use these filters on your 72mm, 67mm, 58mm, 52mm lenses.

Answer (score 6):

**"So why should I buy a UV filter or any other filter for that matter?"**

You don't *need* to buy a UV filter, or any other filter, here is why you would want to use a UV filter specifically:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_filter#Clear_and_ultraviolet

Now I'd say 99% of people who put a UV filter on their lens aren't doing it because of that, they're using it as a layer of protection for the front element of the lens.  Its true, it'll prevent fingers jamming into the element and children's sneezes from getting all over it but there are also downsides which are illustrated in that wikipedia article.  Namely flaring and quality degradation.

Me personally?  I don't use UV filters as all-the-time protection on my lenses anymore (don't want flaring etc), I got a stack of them collecting dust on a shelf.  I bust one out if I'm taking the lens to the ocean or something and anticipate spray but thats about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this filter http://www.amazon.com/Hoya-Ultra-Violet-Coated-Filter/dp/B00009R9A1/ fit my lenses? The Wikipedia articles for these two lenses specify the filter diameter is 58mm, which means this filter will fit my lenses, won't it?

Comment: Thats right, both lenses accept a 58mm filter.  Good call on getting a MC (multi-coated) filter if you're going to get one.

Comment: Merged from: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/which-filters-should-i-be-buying-for-canon-eos-550-d-18-55mm-and-55-250mm-lenses

Answer (score 4):

At the least, I get a clear filter (Hoya usually, sometimes Nikon) just to help protect the lens from surprises that include:

- Accidental spraying (Happens more than you'd think)
- Dusty environments
- Work where you have to go through heavily wooded areas

It puts one cheap peace of glass in front of much more expensive glass. A friend of mine had a $500 prime bite the dust when a passing car kicked up a small rock. What are the chances?? But it does happen.

As for the other filters, it depends entirely on what you are shooting. I usually carry a warming filter, a grad, and maybe a UV depending on what I'm doing. Most of the time, I just leave them at home, with the exception of the clear / protective filter.

Again, its not so much the body, but the lens and the conditions you are shooting in.

Answer (score 4):

I think a polarizing filter is pretty darn necessary. It allows you to manipulate bright sky, water, and clouds in ways that are immediately evident and cannot be fully replicated in post-processing.

Answer (score 4):

If you get a screw-on filter (e.g. a polariser) then you should get a good quality coated one. With digital cameras, the sensor is very reflective, so light entering the camera has a tendency to bounce off the sensor and back off the filter, causing a ghosting effect. This is reduced/eliminated with a coated filter. Note also that a polariser also acts as a 1-2 stop neutral density filter so you will need wider apertures or slower shutter speed/ISO to counter the effect.

Neutral density graduated filters are also very useful, as even though the effect can be reproduced in PP, you will retain more detail in highlit areas using the physical filter. Recovering a blown sky in post risks a weird 'grey border' effect, where saturated highlights that were originally blue become pure white, and when darkened in post turn an incongruous grey. I'm a big fan of getting it right in camera as much as possible, but that's not to say you should NEVER make adjustments afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

There are no "must have" filters. In fact I would recommend that you don't get any. If you are a new photographer you have a lot to learn in terms of exposure, how to operate your camera.

It's all too easy to think that the next piece of gear will allow you to get great shot. But the gear is just a tool. You need to learn the tools and be good at using them. And getting too many tools at the same time just adds to the confusion.

So instead I would recommend spending the money on books helping you in the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go out on a bit of a limb and say there are no filters that you *must* have!

I personally think UV filters are a waste of money, if you think you need it for protection, just be more careful...

I have a circular polariser that I use more than anything else, but to be honest, I only use that for photos of water and clouds etc which I find to be the most boring photos anyway.

Save your money for some nice glass :)

Comment: I completely disagree with you about UV filters being a waste.

Comment: OK, we disagree on whether or not you should use a UV filter. Fine. Personal preference and all that.

I actually think they are useful if you're taking photos in the rain or in a sandstorm.

They have downsides too:
 - You're adding glass (less is more)
 - You're adding a layer of air
 - Increasing chance of flare
 - Cost money (and you don't want to get a cheap one)

A simple lens hood offers better protection for most types of knocks.

Comment: The benefit or otherwise of UV filters is what hackers refer to a a "religious issue" that is:  there are some who feel passionately that UV is essential, while some believe with equal passion that it is a waste of time.  Presonally, I can see the arguments on both sides, and I use UV filters on some lenses but not all.  Can we not realise that this is the case and live in peace all the same?  Let us save our wrath (downvotes) for those who are factually inaccurate.

Comment: Hehe, my thoughts exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the no filter crowd. I prefer the higher quality you get without a filter. Glare reduction with a polarizing filter may be the only exception. Darkening of the sky  with a polarizing filter can be achieved often by use of various layer modes in Photoshop, etc.

As for protection. I've dropped a $1800 70-200 2.8 IS lens and the lens hood took the hit with no damage to the lens. I have lens hoods on all lenses, but no filters.

Answer (score 1):

Just a clear filter for protection and to allow you to clean it without having to touch the actual surface of the lens. That's my advice.
 Get a high quality one, perhaps Hoya and it's really all you need for the vast majority of cases. The only one I would say is work keeping in your bag perhaps is a graduated Neutral Density for darkening skies.
For effects, I now do all my work in Lightroom/Photoshop:
www.talkingpictures.info

Comment: what's your experience of putting a circular polarizor on top of the clear filter?

Answer (score 1):

Neutral density filters have been mentioned because their effect is arguably not possible to be added in post-processing. The polarizer has also been mentioned because its effect is not possible to be added in post.

For completeness, another filter whose effect can arguably not be replicated is the [graduated neutral density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduated_neutral_density_filter) filter. A graduated neutral density filter is clear on one end and a ND filter on the other, allowing the photographer to modify only a portion of the scene. This is particularly important because it can allow the camera to record an otherwise blown-out area of the scene, and therefore can't be fixed in post -- if detail wasn't recorded, it can't be improved.

The result of using a graduated ND filter *can* be recreated in post by taking several exposures and combining them in Photoshop, though the result typically ends up looking a little more like tone-mapped/HDR results.

Answer (score -1):

UV Filters are a must have in my book, for protections sake.

Comment: Subjective, I disagree!

Comment: see also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57/downsides-to-using-a-uv-filter

Comment: yes, many shared there show that it has saved a lens, or should be used to prevent damage.

Comment: It doesn't save a lens that wouldn't have been saved by a lens hood.