# Which filters should I be buying for Canon EOS 550 D, 18-55mm and 55-250mm lenses?

Tags: filters, canon-550d, uv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the must-have filters for a new photographer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-are-the-must-have-filters-for-a-new-photographer)

I'm planning to order my first DSLR: a Canon EOS 550D with 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS Lens, and a 55-250mm f/4.0-5.6 IS Telephoto Zoom Lens. My friend mentioned that I should buy a UV filter, although he couldn't really explain why.

So why should I buy a UV filter or any other filter for that matter? And which ones would you recommend for the camera and lenses that I'm planning to buy?

I also have another question on accessories that I should be buying - I guess it's better to ask that as a separate question. Thanks for your answers and time.