# Filter for Canon EOS M50 Mirrorless Camera Kit w/EF-M15-45mm Lens

Tags: canon, filters

Recently i purchased a Canon EOS M50 Mirrorless Camera Kit w/EF-M15-45mm Len.
i'm a beginner in photography. kindly advise me to find a proper filter for my lens. how can calculate or find the filter size for each different lens and what is the "must have" filter rings for my  Canon EOS M50.

Comment: Voted to close as this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @MikeSowsun We can easily answer "how can calculate or find the filter size for each different lens". The "must have" bit is I agree problematic, but that can be edited out...

Comment: We also have the highly voted but old [What are the must-have filters for a new photographer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-are-the-must-have-filters-for-a-new-photographer).

Comment: https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/ef-m-15-45mm-f-3-5-6-3-is-stm is this lens? The filter size is in the spec sheet.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[image: front view of 15-45]

See that number at the bottom (top if you're standing on your head)? That's the filter size you need.

I'm a sucker for protection filters with hardened glass, but this lens is probably too cheap to justify the cost. Plus, they don't change the image (if best).

I think a C-polarizer filter will give you the most fun, in sunny daylight conditions.

Comment: The question is, does a polarizer for an EOS M need to be circular? Many mirrorless cameras can handle both linear and circular just fine....

Comment: Good point, linear polarizers confuse the AF or AE behind the mirror of an SLR.  But you're gonna have a hard time finding other than circular polarizers anymore, that's where the mass market is. The 1/4 wavelength retarder won't have any influence on the picture, or it might even reduce glare from the reflection of the CMOS sensor.

Comment: Only if you buy your filters new :) Perfectly intact linears tend to be inexpensive on the used market....