# What type of effects can I obtain with UV, FLD, CPL filters if any?

Tags: lens, dslr, filters

Can someone give me examples and show the difference. I obtained [these from amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002P9FOUU). I have played with them for a little while and I am not impressed/bought yet.

UV filter has no affect other than degrading picture
CIRCULAR POLARIZER is impressive, can turn the tv screen into almost black but where can I use it effectively?
FLUORESCENT filter will put is own shade oe the pics, changing the pic them and hence changing the natural colors.

I have heard one reason to use filters is to protect the lens, which I  won't' recommend at the cost of picture quality, myself. I have also heard UV can block some glare when taking pictures in bright sun light and water. For now I have used them only inside though.

Can I take some excellent professional type pictures with the help of these filter, if yes, what type of? If no, What is their use, if any?

Comment: For polarizers: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/655/in-which-situations-should-i-use-my-circular-polarizing-filter

Comment: For UV: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/what-effect-does-uv-filter-provide

Comment: For color-correction filters like the fluorescent type you mention: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/586/are-there-reasons-to-use-colour-filters-with-digital-cameras

Comment: And overall: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/what-types-of-filters-are-there-and-whats-their-use

Comment: You got the 3 filters for just $11.99! These cheap filters would degrade the performance of your lenses to a much larger degree.

Comment: they might but have good reviews otherwise?

Comment: Hello Enthusiast. Given the links mattdm provided, I am not sure this question really brings any additionally useful content to our forum. Are those linked topics sufficient to answer your questions? If so, I think it would be prudent to close this question.

Comment: Exactly, the links are answers. Would wouldn't it be better to put the links in an answer and then close it. Thanks

Comment: I'm still looking for example photos for http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/what-types-of-filters-are-there-and-whats-their-use — and I'm serious about the larger bounty for doing digital approximations as well as real examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community Wiki answer containing the links to similar questions posted by [mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm) as comments:

- [Polarisers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/655/in-which-situations-should-i-use-my-circular-polarizing-filter)
- [UV Filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/what-effect-does-uv-filter-provide)
- [Colour Correction Filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/586/are-there-reasons-to-use-colour-filters-with-digital-cameras)
- [General Overview](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/what-types-of-filters-are-there-and-whats-their-use)

Answer (score 0):

I have the UV filter to protect my lens and I wanted to see the change in quality. It doesn't change any of the colors or anything that I noticed, but it changed the rays of the sun and the "bubbles" that the sun made. Before I got the filter, I took a pic of a Palm tree with the sun shining through. I looked at the picture and noticed the sun and it didn't have rays and it didn't turn out too well, but after, I noticed that the sun was turning out better in my pictures. And btw I take outdoor pictures mostly because I love the sun. Lol and I just started so I may not be the best example. I like it a lot and it's very good at protecting the lens so I recommend it :)