# Are there modern lenses with a 49mm filter diameter?

Tags: filters, filter-diameter

I have found four color-filters in my desk: intense red, orange, light green and light blue. Are there lenses with 49mm filter size which these could be used with?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/586/are-there-reasons-to-use-colour-filters-with-digital-cameras

Comment: Since the color filter question is answered in the duplicate, and since @Imre has answered the _other_ question about the filter size as well, I'm going to go ahead and edit the question to reflect the non-duplicate part only. Violet, please follow the link above to helpful answers on the color filter question in general.

Answer (score 4):

Usage of color filters in digital photography has already been covered in [another question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/586/are-there-reasons-to-use-colour-filters-with-digital-cameras).

There certainly are dozens of [lenses with 49mm filter size](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?filtersize=49) for various mounts, most often for Pentax or Sony. Also, some compact cameras use that filter size, e.g. Fuji X100 (with either AR-X100 adapter or [an extra 49mm filter frame](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qHfsBSLfu8)).

Comment: Today, this answer ("all of them for Pentax and Sony") is not true anymore. The newest Canon "Nifty Fifty" uses 49mm filter. I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't want to pollute this question with 21 answers each describing a single lens.

Comment: @juhist thanks, updated the answer. Luckily the link in answer still correctly reflects current status. The number of matching lenses has grown from 21 to 50 in 8 years.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there are two other possibilities not yet adressed here. Ignoring the debated usefulness or lack of of color filters on digital systems, this is well discussed in the linked question.

- 49mm filters can be used with a step-up ring on modern lenses that have a 40.5mm, 43mm, or 46mm thread, IN SOME CASES (eg full frame lenses used on APS-C) a step-down from 52mm or 55mm could be usable too.
- Adapted manual lenses (arguably modern, arguably not modern :) ) are probably even more common now than in 2011, and 49mm was a very common thread size on SLR lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Sony 50mm f1.8 OSS ( ALC-SH116 )

Answer (score 0):

The commonly used closeup lens Raynox DCR M-250 (and likely a few other closeup lenses from Raynox) has a 49mm filter thread.